# How can I make a button not to move according to the text above it?

Tags: flutter, dart, button

I am developing a pretty basic app in Dart that gives you a random sentence when you click a button. But sometimes this sentence is too big or too small and the button changes its position according to the size of the text above it. How can I make the button stay in a fixed position no matter where the text is?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: "Frases do Dia",
      home: HomeStateful()));
}


class HomeStateful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeStatefulState createState() => _HomeStatefulState();
}


class _HomeStatefulState extends State<HomeStateful> {
  var _texto = 'Clique abaixo para gerar uma frase!';
  List frasesdodia = [
    '"Construir uma empresa é como assar um bolo. Você precisa ter todos os ingredientes na proporção certa."',
    '"Se você acorda de manhã e pensa que o futuro será melhor, é um dia bom. Se não, não é."',
    '"Quando Henry Ford produziu carros baratos e confiáveis, as pessoas falaram "não, nós temos cavalos". Ele fez uma grande aposta. E funcionou."',
    '"O caminho do CEO não deve ser por meio do escritório do CFO e nem no departamento de marketing. Precisa ser através de engenharia e design."',
    '"Acho que esse é o melhor conselho de todos: pense constantemente sobre como você pode fazer as coisas melhor e questione a si mesmo."',
    '"Devem existir razões pelas quais você acorda de manhã e quer viver. O que você ama sobre o futuro? Se o futuro não incluir estar lá fora, nas estrelas, e ser uma espécie multiplanetária, eu acho extremamente triste."',
    '"A paciência é uma virtude. E eu estou aprendendo a tê-la. É uma lição difícil."',
    '"Se algo é importante o suficiente, você deve tentar. Mesmo se o resultado provável for o fracasso."'
  ];
  var s = new Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            title: Center(
              child: Text(
                "Frases do Dia",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
               ))
            )),
            
        body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(children: [
              Center(
                  child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 170),
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png"),
              )),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 50),
                  child: Text(
                    _texto,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                  )),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(),
                child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _texto = frasesdodia[s.nextInt(frasesdodia.length)];
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Nova Frase",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.white))),
              )
            ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a potential solution (although there are many).

The central `Padding` widget, surrounding your changing text, resizes itself according to its child (a `Text` Widget in this case).

When the text is less, `Padding` takes up less space.  When text is larger, `Padding` will take up more space, in order to fit the `Text` widget.

`Column` children take only the amount of space they need, so when one of the children changes size, it will affect other child widgets in the `Column`.

By wrapping the `Padding`/`Text` widgets in a `SizedBox` with a fixed height value, that central child in the `Column` no longer changes size when text length changes.  This way, your last child in `Column`, the `Button` containing widget, will remain in the same position relative to the other children & on screen.

I've wrapped the center and bottom `Column` children in Containers and added colors to help visualize how much space each widget is taking and how it is aligned.

Note that when `Container` alignment is center, it will expand to fill as much space as it can.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class TextSizeButtonPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TextSizeButtonPageState createState() => _TextSizeButtonPageState();
}


class _TextSizeButtonPageState extends State<TextSizeButtonPage> {
  var _texto = 'Clique abaixo para gerar uma frase!';
  List frasesdodia = [
    '"Construir uma empresa é como assar um bolo. Você precisa ter todos os ingredientes na proporção certa."',
    '"Se você acorda de manhã e pensa que o futuro será melhor, é um dia bom. Se não, não é."',
    '"Quando Henry Ford produziu carros baratos e confiáveis, as pessoas falaram "não, nós temos cavalos". Ele fez uma grande aposta. E funcionou."',
    '"O caminho do CEO não deve ser por meio do escritório do CFO e nem no departamento de marketing. Precisa ser através de engenharia e design."',
    '"Acho que esse é o melhor conselho de todos: pense constantemente sobre como você pode fazer as coisas melhor e questione a si mesmo."',
    '"Devem existir razões pelas quais você acorda de manhã e quer viver. O que você ama sobre o futuro? Se o futuro não incluir estar lá fora, nas estrelas, e ser uma espécie multiplanetária, eu acho extremamente triste."',
    '"A paciência é uma virtude. E eu estou aprendendo a tê-la. É uma lição difícil."',
    '"Se algo é importante o suficiente, você deve tentar. Mesmo se o resultado provável for o fracasso."'
  ];
  var s = new Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            title: Center(
                child: Text(
                    "Frases do Dia",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ))
            )),

        body: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(30),
            child: Column(children: [
              Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                    child: Image.network('https://i.pravatar.cc/150?img=28'),
                  )),
              SizedBox(
                height: 150,
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 50, 0, 50),
                      child: Text(
                        _texto,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _texto = frasesdodia[s.nextInt(frasesdodia.length)];
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Nova Frase",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: Colors.white))),
              ),
            ])));
  }
}
```